# Можно ли доменное имя использовать повторно?

Tags: nginx, dns, развертывание

Я настраиваю nginx для деплоя flask-приложения на vps.
Для этого я сначала пробую настраивать у себя на собственном компьютере в линуксе.
После успешной проверки что всё работает делаю те же самые действия с настройками уже на сервере хостера (там тоже линукс).

Один из шагов - нужно приобрести доменное имя.
Вот оно у меня появилось, могу ли я его использовать вначале на своем линуксе, а потом на линуксе хостера? Или его можно только единожды использовать?

nginx использую в связке с gunicorn

Comment: что вы имеете в виду под использованием на своем линуксе?

Comment: @Эникейщик думаю подразумевается локальная машина

Comment: @Dmitry эта часть понятна. Непонятна часть с доменным именем :)

Comment: @Эникейщик ТС хочет использовать одно и то же доменное имя на продакшн и на тест сервер. Но я понимаю, что это все дело разнесено и вряд ли есть смысл в этом

Comment: Да, свой линукс - это который на локальной машине. Также у меня есть место на сервере, vps, которое мне предоставила хостинговая компания. Моя цель - чтоб было видно мое flask-приложение всему миру в интернете (то есть надо задеплоить). Я тестирую на своей локальной машине, а потом пробую те же самые действия на сервере хостера. Но не понятно, можно ли при настройке nginx + gunicorn, и на локалке и на vps хостера использовать одно и то же доменное имя.

Comment: @Muriam если коротко, то нет

Comment: ну да, мне уже ответили в чате. То есть надо настраивать только на vps, на локальном компьютере не надо тестить предворительно

Comment: @Muriam все надо тестить, только это отдельная часть разработки. Эту часть тоже можно автоматирзировать до тех пор пока вам не надоест. В общих словах, у вас есть проект в продакшн, вы пишете новый функционал локально, далее отправляете команду на автоматические тесты, далее функционал добавляется в продакшн. Это отдельная, но интересная часть

Comment: @Dmitry, `если коротко, то нет` — как-то уж очень категорично. ну, автор вопроса, допустим, просто не знает про существование и смысл файла `/etc/hosts`. но зачем же вместо предложения этим файлом воспользоваться, сообщать ему, что это невозможно?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin напишите ответ, я тоже не знал об этом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы должны понять, как работает `DNS`. Первое и главное при приобритении доменного имени оно у вас будет привязано к IP адресу, по которому и будет располагаться ваш сервис. То есть, как я понимаю это ваш продакшн-сервер. Для тестов не обязательно иметь доменное имя, можно все сделать симуляцией. Например, я использую виртуальный сервер на который проброшены порты с реальной машины. Я могу обращаться к виртуальному серверу по <ip:port>. Этого достаточно, чтобы протестить основой функционал. Но так же, я имею доменное имя для тестов, но повышается риск слить данные, поэтомоу очень редко использую.

Выделю:

**DNS — это система для связывания доменных имен с соответствующими им IP-адресами. Служба хранит информацию об ip адресах, обеспечивает их кэширование и отдачу информацию пользователю**